# How to restore data in Listview

Tags: sqlite, flutter

My goal is restoring data from sql database to Listview. Firstly, I started with creating database and model class. Secondly I realized that I have to use FutureBuilder. But I can't understood, how to use this stuff in my case. In addition I have known, that have to use GlobalKey.

> This is my code. In this version of my code, Alert dialog doesn't work

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:path/path.dart';
import 'dart:ui';
import 'package:samuraigym/program_training_handler.dart';
import 'package:samuraigym/my_icons_icons.dart' as custicon;
import 'package:sqflite/sqflite.dart';
import 'package:path_provider/path_provider.dart';
import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:io' as io;
import 'package:fluttertoast/fluttertoast.dart';
class MeasurementsScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MeasurementsScreenState createState() => _MeasurementsScreenState();
}

class _MeasurementsScreenState extends State<MeasurementsScreen> {
  List<ListItem> listItems;
  final scaffoldKey = new GlobalKey<ScaffoldState>();
  final formKey = new GlobalKey<FormState>();
  String typeOfMuscle;
  String numberOfMuscle;

  var nameItem = ["Рост","Вес","Шея","Плечевой пояс","Грудь","Бицепс",
    "Предплечье","Запястье","Живот","Бедро","Голень","Лодыжка"];
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    initListItems();
  }

  void initListItems() {
    listItems = [
      new ListItem(
          detail: nameItem[0],
          index: 0,
          data: " "),
      new ListItem(
          detail: nameItem[1],
          index: 1,
          data: " "),
      new ListItem(
          detail: nameItem[2],
          index: 2,
          data: " "),
      new ListItem(
          detail: nameItem[3],
          index: 3,
          data: " "),
      new ListItem(
          detail: nameItem[4],
          index: 4,
          data: " "),
      new ListItem(
          detail: nameItem[5],
          index: 5,
          data: " "),
      new ListItem(
          detail: nameItem[6],
          index: 6,
          data: " "),
      new ListItem(
          detail: nameItem[7],
          index: 7,
          data: " "),
      new ListItem(
          detail: nameItem[8],
          index: 8,
          data: " "),
      new ListItem(
          detail: nameItem[9],
          index: 9,
          data: " "),
      new ListItem(
          detail: nameItem[10],
          index: 10,
          data: " "),
      new ListItem(
          detail: nameItem[11],
          index: 11,
          data: " ")


    ];
  }
  void sumbitContact(int index, String numberOfMuscle) {
    if(this.formKey.currentState.validate())
      formKey.currentState.save();
    else
      return null;

    var measurementsDatabaseModel = MeasurementsDatabaseModel();
    measurementsDatabaseModel.numberOfMuscle = numberOfMuscle;
    measurementsDatabaseModel.typeOfMuscle = index as String;

    var dbHelper = DatabaseHelperForMeasurements();
    dbHelper.addNewMeasurementsDatabaseModel(measurementsDatabaseModel);
    Fluttertoast.showToast(msg: 'Contact was saved',
        toastLength: Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);

  }
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Scaffold(
      key: scaffoldKey,
      backgroundColor: Color(0xff2b2b2b),
      appBar: AppBar(
        backgroundColor: Colors.lightGreen[400],
        title: Text(
          'Замеры',
          style: new TextStyle(
            color: Colors.white
          ),),
        leading: IconButton(
          icon:Icon(Icons.arrow_back),
          color: Colors.white ,
          onPressed:() => Navigator.of(context).pop(),
        ),
      ),
      body: FutureBuilder<List<MeasurementsDatabaseModel>>(
        future: getMeasurementsDatabaseModelFromDB(),
        builder: (context, snapshot){
        if(snapshot.data != null  && snapshot.hasData){
          return  ListView.builder(
            physics: BouncingScrollPhysics(),
            itemCount: listItems.length,
            itemBuilder: (BuildContext ctxt, int index) => listItems[index],
          );
        } else {
          return ListView.builder(
            physics: BouncingScrollPhysics(),
            itemCount: listItems.length,
            itemBuilder: (BuildContext ctxt, int index) => listItems[index],
          );
        }
        }
      )
    );
  }



}

Future<List<MeasurementsDatabaseModel>> getMeasurementsDatabaseModelFromDB() async {
  var dbHelper = DatabaseHelperForMeasurements();
  Future<List<MeasurementsDatabaseModel>> contacts = dbHelper.getMeasurementsDatabaseModel();
  return contacts;
}

class ListItem extends StatefulWidget {
  String detail;
  int index;
  String data;
  _MeasurementsScreenState measurementsScreen;
  ListItem({Key key, this.detail, this.index, this.data}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _ListItem createState() => _ListItem(measurementsScreen);
}
class _ListItem extends State<ListItem>  {
  bool isAppear = false;
  final _MeasurementsScreenState measurementsScreen;
  DatabaseHelperForMeasurements db  = DatabaseHelperForMeasurements();
  _ListItem(this.measurementsScreen);
  MeasurementsDatabaseModel measurementsDatabaseModel = new MeasurementsDatabaseModel();
  String typeOfMuscle;
  String numberOfMuscle;

  String lastSelectedValue;
  var name = ["Рост","Вес","Шея","Плечевой пояс","Грудь","Бицепс",
    "Предплечье","Запястье","Живот","Бедро","Голень","Лодыжка"];
  var indication = ["Ваш рост","Ваш вес","Ваша шея","Ваш плечевой пояс","Ваша грудь","Ваш бицепс",
    "Ваше предплечье","Ваше запястье","Ваш живот","Ваше бедро","Ваша голень","Ваша лодыжка"];
  var prefix = ["см: ","кг: ","см: ","см: ","см: ","см: ","см: ","см: ","см: ","см: ","см: ","см: "];
  var prefixAlert = ["см","кг","см","см","см","см","см","см","см","см","см","см"];
  TextEditingController customcintroller;


  Future<String> createAlertDialog(BuildContext context, int indexAl) async{
    customcintroller = TextEditingController();
      String returnVal = await showDialog(
          context: context, builder: (context){
        return AlertDialog(
          title: Text(name[indexAl]),
          content: TextFormField(
            textDirection: TextDirection.ltr,
            controller: customcintroller,
            style: TextStyle(
                color: Colors.lightGreen[400],
                fontSize: 18.5),
            decoration: InputDecoration(
              contentPadding: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 4.0),
              labelText: indication[indexAl],
              suffixText: prefixAlert[widget.index],
              alignLabelWithHint: false,
            ),
            keyboardType: TextInputType.phone,
            textInputAction: TextInputAction.done,
            onSaved: (val) => this.numberOfMuscle = val,

          ),
          actions: <Widget>[
            FlatButton(
              child: const Text('ОТМЕНА'),
              onPressed: () {
                Navigator.of(context).pop();
              },
            ),
            FlatButton(
              child: const Text('ОК'),
              onPressed: () {
                setState(() {
                  widget.data = customcintroller.text.toString();
                  isAppear = !isAppear;
                  measurementsScreen.sumbitContact(widget.index, widget.data);
                  getMeasurementsDatabaseModelFromDB();
                  Navigator.of(context).pop();
                });
              },
            ),
          ],
        );
      });

      return returnVal;

  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      child: GestureDetector(
        onTap: () {
          createAlertDialog(context, widget.index);
        },
        child: Container(
          color: Color(0xff2b2b2b),
          height: 55.0,
          margin: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
            vertical: 1.0,
          ),
          child: new Stack(
            children: <Widget>[
              new Container(
                child: new SizedBox.expand(
                  child: Container(
                    alignment: Alignment.center,
                    child: new Row(
                      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                      mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                      children: <Widget>[
//                    Padding(
//                      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
//                    child: Icon(
//                      custicon.MyIcons.bathroom_scale,
//                      color: Colors.lightGreen[400],
//                      size: 40.0)),
                        Padding(
                          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
                          child: new Text(
                            widget.detail,
                            style:
                            new TextStyle(fontSize: 16.0, color: Colors.white),
                          ),
                        ),
                        Container(
                          alignment: Alignment.centerRight,
                          child: isAppear ? Padding(
                              padding: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                              child: Container(
                                  decoration: ShapeDecoration(
                                    color: Colors.lightGreen[400],
                                    shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                                      side: BorderSide(width: 1.0, style: BorderStyle.solid, color: Colors.white),
                                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(5.0)),
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                  child: Padding(
                                      padding: EdgeInsets.all(4.0),
                                      child: new Text(
                                        prefix[widget.index] + widget.data,
                                        style: new TextStyle(
                                            fontSize: 16.0,
                                            color: Colors.white
                                        ),
                                      )))) : SizedBox(),
                        )
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        )));
  }
}
class MeasurementsDatabaseModel{
  int id;
  String typeOfMuscle;
  String numberOfMuscle;
  MeasurementsDatabaseModel();
}
class DatabaseHelperForMeasurements{
  static Database db_instance;
  final String TABLE_NAME = "Measurements";

  Future<Database> get db async{
    if(db_instance == null)
      db_instance = await initDB();
    return db_instance;
  }
  initDB() async {
    io.Directory documentsDirectory = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
    String path = join(documentsDirectory.path,"Measurements_db.db");
    var db = await openDatabase(path,version: 1, onCreate: onCreateFunc);
    return db;
  }

  void onCreateFunc(Database db, int version) async{

    await db.execute('CREATE TABLE $TABLE_NAME(id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, typeOfMuscle TEXT, numberOfMuscle TEXT);');

  }

  Future<List<MeasurementsDatabaseModel>> getMeasurementsDatabaseModel() async{
    var db_connection = await db;
    List<Map> list = await db_connection.rawQuery('SELECT * FROM $TABLE_NAME');
    List<MeasurementsDatabaseModel> modelList = new List();
    for(int i = 0; i < list.length; i++){
      MeasurementsDatabaseModel measurementsDatabaseModel = new MeasurementsDatabaseModel();
      measurementsDatabaseModel.id = list[i]['id'];
      measurementsDatabaseModel.typeOfMuscle = list[i]['typeOfMuscle'];
      measurementsDatabaseModel.numberOfMuscle = list[i]['numberOfMuscle'];

      modelList.add(measurementsDatabaseModel);
    }
    return modelList;
  }

  void addNewMeasurementsDatabaseModel(MeasurementsDatabaseModel measurementsDatabaseModel) async {
    var db_connection = await db;
    String query =
        'INSERT INTO $TABLE_NAME(name,phone) VALUES( \'${measurementsDatabaseModel.typeOfMuscle}\',\'${measurementsDatabaseModel.numberOfMuscle}\')';
    await db_connection.transaction((transition) async{
      return await transition.rawInsert(query);
    });
  }
  void updateMeasurementsDatabaseModel(MeasurementsDatabaseModel measurementsDatabaseModel) async {
    var db_connection = await db;
    String query =
        'UPDATE $TABLE_NAME SET name =\'${measurementsDatabaseModel.typeOfMuscle}\',phone =\'${measurementsDatabaseModel.typeOfMuscle}\' WHERE id =${measurementsDatabaseModel.id}';
    await db_connection.transaction((transition) async{
      return await transition.rawQuery(query);
    });
  }
  void deleteMeasurementsDatabaseModel(MeasurementsDatabaseModel measurementsDatabaseModel) async {
    var db_connection = await db;
    String query = 'DELETE FROM $TABLE_NAME WHERE id = ${measurementsDatabaseModel.id}';
    await db_connection.transaction((transition) async{
      return await transition.rawQuery(query);
    });
  }
}
```

This is gif, where I want to save data. How can you see, there is container with text near right part of screen. There I want to save data, which I put in AlertDialog.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, we are going to discuss its simplified implementation. At the MainScreen,
we won't connect it to SQLite. But later on, We can discuss more complex 
implementation by calling SQLite queries.

#### Should we use FutureBuilder ?

In many tutorials spread accross internet, app screen can shows Loading indicator, and later on, it shows ListView and its ListTile **after fetching to Database.**

It works well if ***there are no further interaction*** with ListView later on.

As we using future, the builder will only **triggered twice**.

```dart
class MainScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      child: FutureBuilder(
        future: queryDatabase(), // Calling Database
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.hasData) { // After Callback, it may triggers this Part
            return ListView.builder(
              itemBuilder: (_, index) {
                return ListTile(
                  title: Text("$index"),
                );
              },
            );
          }
          return Center( // First Triggering this Part
            child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
          );
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

#### The solution is Stateful Widget !

By using Stateful Widget, we can store our products, in variable. Therefore, 
each time MainScreen's build method called, the app will display updated List.

```dart
class MainScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MainScreenState createState() => _MainScreenState();
}

class _MainScreenState extends State<MainScreen> {
  List<Map<String, dynamic>> products = []; // Store Item, Here

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(...),
      body: Container(
        child: renderProducts(), // Render stored Item, here
      ),
    );
  }
```

We can see at the demo below, as we interact with buttons, the build method
always being **re-called**, and **fortunately, we can have our Expected Screen**

[image: Demo]

#### Identified Problems

```dart
class _ListItem extends State<ListItem>  {
  String typeOfMuscle;
  String numberOfMuscle;
  TextEditingController customcintroller;
  ...

  AlertDialog(
    title: Text(name[indexAl]),
    content: TextFormField(
      controller: customcintroller,
      onSaved: (val) => this.numberOfMuscle = val,
    ),
  );
),
```

the problem is, in `onSaved` method, the app will only update local variable that
resides on each of `ListItem`. Therefore, the app does not know that the new value 
should be displayed.

**How to make the widget `rerenders` ?**

By using `setState((){})` as the code below

```dart
class _ListItem extends State<ListItem>  {
  String typeOfMuscle;
  String numberOfMuscle;
  TextEditingController customcintroller;
  ...

  void updateAndRerender(val){
    this.numberOfMuscle = val;
    setState((){});
  }

  AlertDialog(
    title: Text(name[indexAl]),
    content: TextFormField(
      controller: customcintroller,
      onSaved: (val) {
        updateAndRerender(val);
      },
    ),
  );
),
```

#### Working Example-App Repo

you may look into this repository. [Github](https://github.com/ejabu/flutter_sqlite_list)